# Python: how to combine mpi4py and mutiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi4py

I have the following two parts of code, first one is the code using multiprocessing and the second one is with mpi4py.

Multiporecessing one

```
def simple(data): #(np.arrray) # its a function from other module
result = do something with the data
return result #(np.arrray)

def lesssimple(data, num):
    num_cores = num
    inputs = tqdm(x)
    processed_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(simple)(i, num) for i in inputs)
    return processed_list
```

Mpi4py one

```
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank() 
size = comm.Get_size()


if rank == 0: 
     data = np.array_split(dat, size) 
else:
     data = None


recvbuf = comm.scatter(data, root=0)

result = []
for item in recvbuf:
    result.append(somefunction(item))


newData = comm.gather(result,root=0)
if rank == 0:
      with open('result.data', 'wb') as filehandle:
      pickle.dump(newData, filehandle)
```

My question is that if I want to make a multiprocessing jobs in each of the nodes specified by the Mpi4py, can simply combine them like below?  (the computation is independent for each data in the list, no need for communication).

```
#all the others the same with mpi4py    

result = []
for item in recvbuf:
   result.append(lesssimple(data, num)) ### plugging the multiprocessing function into this part

#all the others the same with mpi4py
```